# I think my CPU is returning wrong temperatures

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kernel, cpu, nvme

My Ubuntu 20 is freezing here and there since I changed my disk to a NVMe SSD.

While debugging for kernel logs I noticed these errors:

```
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 9314)
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[sex dez  4 11:34:55 2020] mce: CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
```

This is how my CPU temp looks at the moment of this messages:

[image]

So as you can see, nothing unusual, and the kernel messages also state that within the same second, all CPU are both above threshold and also at a normal temperature.

Like, what the hell? What is going on?

https://streamable.com/6qq26o

Comment: I suspect hardware.  Following a hardware change, are you sure that there is still room for airflow in the machine?  Could a cable have obstructed a fan?  What kind of processor do you have?  There are thermal specifications published by manufacturers.

Comment: 73C at idle? That's a lot! Check your fans and maybe you'll need to reapply your CPU thermal paste.

Comment: It was not in idle. I had firefox and intelij opened. I have reapplied paste 1 week ago (and didn't notice any difference). On windows I see the temperature changing from 60ºC to 90ºC and back to 60ºC in less than a second. As if it is measuring a noise signal instead of the real CPU temp. Very strange.

Comment: Here's a video https://streamable.com/6qq26o

Comment: Is it a laptop? (I guess not since 6 cores, but the thermals seem awfully familiar)

Comment: Yes, it is. I think I fixed this issue using the answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526671/how-to-solve-the-cpufreqset-errors

Comment: I forced the freq to 2.0GHz, and now all seems stable